# Creating Folder using php and user id through php session

Tags: php, web

So I want to make a little web app for me and my family and the thing that does not work is the session that is set in `verify.php`:

```
$sql_select = 'select id from email="'.$_SESSION['name'].'" ';

$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$id = $row['id'];
$_SESSION['id']= $id;
header('Location: home.php');
exit;
```

And then I will make a folder and insert and image in `upload.php`

```
<?php
session_start();

$id = $_SESSION['id']; 
var_dump($_SESSION);
$gallery = 'gallery';
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/files/'.$id.'/'.$gallery.'/';
@mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
    $dir.$_FILES['file']['name']
);
```

The image is just uploading to a gallery folder but not to the actual users folder and this comes out when I  `var_dump` the `$_SESSION`

```
array(3) { ["logged_in"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> NULL ["id"]=> NULL }
```

But I am sure the session is alive.

Comment: Is the session started in the first file before it's being used?  Also, that SQL query is invalid and probably resulting in an error.  (It's also open to SQL injection attacks.)

Comment: Yes there is , can't get my head around it :p

Comment: What exactly fails? Creating a folder, using the session, the mysql statement? While context is relevant to a question, boil it down to only the necessary bits.